# string appears as subset of character in list element python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, subset

So far, I have:

```py
my_list = ['hello', 'oi']
comparison_list = ['this hellotext', 'this oitext']

for w in my_list:
    if w in comparison_list: print('yes')
```

However, nothing prints because no element in `my_list` equals any element in `comparison_list`.

So how do I make this check as a subset or total occurance?

Ideal output:

```
yes
yes
```

Comment: Please let me know if I need to further clarify.

Comment: Had to wait a bit. Done now. Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the occurrence of the complete string in the list currently. Instead you can check for the occurrence of the string inside each comparison string and make a decision. A simple approach will be to re-write the loop as below

```
for w in my_list:
    # Check for every comparison string. any() considers atleast 1 true value
    if any([True for word in comparison_list if w in word]):
        print('yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're comparing `w` to the list elements. If you wanna find `w` in each string in your `comparison_list` you can use `any`:

```
my_list = ['hello', 'oi', 'abcde']
comparison_list = ['this hellotext', 'this oitext']

for w in my_list:
    if any(w in s for s in comparison_list):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

I added a string to your list and handle the 'no' case in order to get an output for each element

Output:

```
yes
yes
no
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited Solution:**
Apologies for older solution, I was confused somehow.

Using re module , we can use re.search to determine if the string is present in the list of items. To do this we can create an expression using str.join to concatenate all the strings using `|`. Once the expression is created we can iterate through the list of comparison to be done. Note | means 'Or', so any of the searched strings if present should return bool value of True. Note I am assuming there are no special characters present in the my_list.

```
 import re
 reg =  '|'.join(my_list)
 for item in comparison_list:
     print(bool(re.search(reg, item)))
```

Comment: This might not work if there are more words in my_list. Eg. ['hello', 'oi', 'tex', 'ext']

Comment: @Kris, Thanks for the comment. I was confused with parllel matching, thought he wanted to perform parallel matching, nevertheless, edited the solution

Comment: Great! this is more elegant!